# How to get the particular product price detail from any shopping websites in php?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I want to get the particular price detail from the shopping website. I want the update of the price details. Tried with DOM parser but not get any succesfull result and i dont want amazon API.

When am using file_get_html its not get the url , but i edit the url to 'http://www.amazon.in' its working.

$html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.in/Logitech-Wireless-Bluetooth-Speaker-Yellow/dp/B00HR34WMA/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1502542820&sr=8-2&keywords=x100');

RESULT : $html=Empty.

Help me guys.

Comment: When am using the link..file_get_html not get it

Comment: $html = file_get_html('http://www.amazon.in/Logitech-Wireless-Bluetooth-Speaker-Yellow/dp/B00HR34WMA/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1502542820&sr=8-2&keywords=x100');

Comment: Edit your question to include all info instead of adding additional info in comments.

Comment: Okay..will do that

Comment: _"Tried with DOM parser but not get any succesfull result"_ - Show us what you tried and what actually happened. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please Check i have updated the answer

Comment: Sorry for the in convenience

Comment: Advice: stop using simple_html_dom (that isn't so simple) and use DOMDocument that is faster.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the site provides API's to the developers for this or you have to write a web crawler - atleast a limited version for this

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way, since the OP stated: _"i dont want amazon API"_ and also already tried to make a crawler (using DOM parser).